# dotnet restore with custom source and official feed

Tags: .net-core

I have custom Nuget repository (\\build\NugetFeed) and also i'm using nuget.org to restore my packages.

For restoring packages I use this command

```
dotnet restore --source \\build\NugetFeed --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --verbosity n
```

But on my build server I get the following error

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.107\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : The local source 'D:\BuildAgent\_work\5\s\https:\api.nuget.org\v3\index.json' doesn't exist. [D:\BuildAgent\_work\5\s\MyCode.sln]
```

and no packages from official Nuget is restored.
Is there any another config options for using dotnet restore?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Seems like a dotnet cli restore command error.

It fails if you specify the local origin first, but works otherwise.

```
# Fails
dotnet restore --source /tmp/Nuget --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

```
#Works
dotnet restore --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --source /tmp/Nuget
```

Anyway, you can always use a custom Nuget.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="local" value="/tmp/Nuget" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

or even add it to the project itself

```xml
 <PropertyGroup>
      <RestoreSources>$(RestoreSources);https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json;/tmp/Nuget</RestoreSources>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

[This issue seems related](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/1622).

Comment: Such an awesome `dotnet restore` bug