# Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore, build-pipeline

I have a `dotnet core` project which builds fine locally but throws the following error many times:

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://mycontrol.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/f8292c33-blah-blah-blah-e5e14bb9ba87/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.net.test.sdk/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

This error appears in the VSTS build log for every package used in the project.

Opening the link shows this:

```
{
$id: "1",
innerException: null,
message: "Can't find the package 'microsoft.net.test.sdk' in feed 'MyFeeds'.",
typeName: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.NuGet.WebApi.Exceptions.PackageNotFoundException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.NuGet.WebApi",
typeKey: "PackageNotFoundException",
errorCode: 0,
eventId: 3000
}
```

Though I do not have a `NuGet.Config` in the project folder, I do have one in the parent folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="_nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="_myget.org" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/mstestv2/api/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I will also get this error (but only for 1 or 2 packages in the log):

```
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.1.701\NuGet.targets(121,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'specflow' from remote source 'https://apsourcecontrol.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/98e0f10f-afcb-4c74-a075-37c564e0408a/nuget/v3/flat2/specflow/index.json'. [D:\a\1\s\Testing\Tester\MsTester\MsTester.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.1.701\NuGet.targets(121,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [D:\a\1\s\Testing\Tester\MsTester\MsTester.csproj]
```

If all I get for an application is the first error then the build succeeds, but if I get 1 or more of the second error the build fails.

What do I need to do in order to tell `dotnet core` where to source the packages from?

**[EDIT]** I have tried placing the `NuGet.Config` in the project folder, to no avail.

**[EDIT-2]** I have it working. The solution was to place the `NuGet` sources in the `csproj` file, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231929/71376

Comment: Have you use the dotnet restore task to restore the nuget packages before you build the pipeline? If yes, could you please share your dotnet restore task build pipeline definition to us?

Comment: Again, AFAIK, there is an issue on `.NET SDK 2.1.500`, not sure if it fixed at 2.1.701, as workaround, you can try to add the Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages package source in the nuget.config to check if it works for you:https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7524

Comment: The build pipeline does use a restore task in a powershell script but I don't think I can share the script. I will need to check the SDK version but I simply haven't had time. I will get back to you when I can. Thank you for the info.

Comment: The "Use .NET Core" step is configured to install version "2.1.x" and the PS script simply performs a dotnet restore on the specific csproj file. As the pipeline is working now I'm not going to add the offline packages unless it breaks again. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Im having the same problem. Using VS2022 preview and getting this problem in build pipeline. The final solution was that you skipped Nuget.config in solution and added packages soruces in project files instead?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar error but building locally and with the `Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync'` and the package `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask`

The build was failing but I was able to debug and get the Azure Functions to work even with the failed build.

In the end, I just added that package to the project. Oddly, no .csproj changes were committed to the repo, so I believe the reference was already there, but somehow broken. Honestly, this part of not having a .csproj change, I still cannot explain... but the build error has gone away. :)